# how to make the border of a text field change color when the cursor is inside flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to change the color of the border but only when the cursor is in the text field

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focusedBorder` in this case.

```dart
TextFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12,),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.pink,
    )
  )
),
),
```

You can find more about [`InputDecoration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

Comment: This is very good thank you but I used a TextField widget. Any solution to that?

Comment: You can simply convert it to `TextFormField`